# webassets + jinja2 bundle error

Tags: python, jinja2, webassets

I am trying to define a Bundle on the fly in a template file using webassets package for python and jinja2 however I keep getting errors:

> BundleError: '/docroot/static/css/base.css' does not exist

```
{% assets filters='cssutils,gzip', output="css/style.css", "css/base.css", "css/datePicker.min.css", "css/bootstrap-1.2.0.css" %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ ASSET_URL }}" />
{% endassets %}
```

http://elsdoerfer.name/docs/webassets/integration/jinja2.html

Answer (score 0):

It's because webassets is not thread safe:

https://github.com/miracle2k/django-assets/issues/12